# Any way for leader dots to extend from inside the text?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

I think it's best to explain with the image above, is there a way to make the dots extend all the way to the volume? Whatever I try the text on the left is inside a block with a set width so the dots are contained inside of it and I can't use a white background to only cover the text area.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/warhammered_cat/pen/wvWXzPw?editors=1100)

```css
.two-line-menu-item {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

.two-line-menu-item__title {
  color: #4ca099;
}

.two-line-menu-item-info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.two-line-menu-item-info__type-vol {
  max-width: 70%;
  padding-right: 0.33rem;
  background-color: white;
}

.two-line-menu-item-info__price {
  padding-left: 0.33rem;
  background-color: white;
}

.dots {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -9px;
  height: 3px;
  border-top: 3px dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-line-menu-item">
  <div class="title-text two-line-menu-item__title">Cappy Juices</div>
  <div class="two-line-menu-item-info">
    <span class="two-line-menu-item-info__type-vol">orange, apple, apricot, peach, black currant, smoothie 0.2 l</span>
    <span class="two-line-menu-item-info__price">16 kn</span>
  </div>
  <div class="dots"></div>
</div>
```